# Why is the Newton Iteration Guaranteed to Converge in This Case?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, newton-raphson

I am working on the following problem:

> Consider using Newton’s method to find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F(x) = 0,$  for $F:D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $D$ is open and convex and $F$ is continuously differentiable on $D$. Suppose $x^∗$ satisfies $F(x∗) = 0$; and $J(x)$, the Jacobian of $F$ evaluated at $x$ satisfies $‖J^{−1}(x)‖\le \mu$ for some number $\mu > 0$ for all $x$ in a convex neighborhood $N \subseteq D$ that contains $x^∗$.
>
> Assuming there is a constant $v$ such that $‖J(y)−J(x)‖≤v‖y−x‖$ for each $x,y \in N$, show that $\{x_k \}$ converges quadratically to $x^∗$ whenever $x_0 \in N.$

I have been able to solve the problem, but only by imposing two additional assumptions: $N$ is a ball centered at $x^*$, and $||x_0 - x^*|| < \frac 1M$ where $M = \frac 12 \mu v.$

\begin{align*}
\\
\end{align*}

**My Partial Solution:**

Suppose that for some $k \ge 0$ we have $x_k \in N$, and that for $m = 0, 1, 2, ..., k-1$ we have $||x_{m+1} - x^*|| \le M ||x_m - x^*||^2$
where $M = \frac 12 v \mu$.

Let $h = x_k - x^*$ and define
$$G(t) = F(x^* + th)$$
for $t \in [0, 1]$. Since $x^*, x_k \in N$ and $N$ is convex, $x^* + th \in N$ for every $t$. Thus $G$ is differentiable on $[0, 1]$ with $G'(t) =  J(x^* + th)h$.

\begin{align*}
||x_{k+1} - x^*|| &= ||x_k - J^{-1}(x_k) F(x_k) - x^*||\\
\\
& \le ||J^{-1}(x_k)|| \cdot ||J(x_k)(x_k - x^*) - F(x_k)|| \\
\\
&\le \mu || J(x_k)(x_k - x^*) - (F(x_k) - F(x^*) )||\\
\\
& = \mu|| G'(1) - (G(1) - G(0))||\\
\\
& =  \mu|| \int_0^1 G'(1) dt - \int_0^1 G'(t) dt||\\
\\
& \le \mu \int_0^1 ||G'(1) - G'(t)|| dt \\
\\
& \le \mu ||x_k - x^*|| \int_0^1 ||J(1) - J(x^* + th)|| dt\\
\\
& \le \mu ||x_k - x^*|| \int_0^1 t v ||h|| dt
\\
& \le \mu ||x_k - x^*||^2 \frac 12 v \\
\\
& = M ||x_k - x^*||^2.
\end{align*}

Let $y_m = ||x_m - x^*||$. We would like to prove that $y_m \to 0$. We have

\begin{align*}
y_1 &\le My_0^2\\
y_2 &\le My_1^2 \le M^3 y_0^4\\
y_3 &\le My_2^2 \le M^7 y_0^8\\
&\vdots \\
y_m &\le M^{2^{m}-1} y_0^{2^m} = \frac 1M \left(M y_0\right)^{2^m}
\end{align*}

Now if $y_0 < \frac 1M$ (assumed in my additional hypothesis), then
$$y_{m+1} < \frac 1M (1)^{2m+2} = \frac 1M = y_0$$
This means that $x_{k}$ is closer to $x^*$ than $x_{k+1}$ is, and if $N$ is a ball (my other additional hypothesis) then $x_{k+1}$ is also in $N$.

Finally, $y_0 < 1M \implies \frac 1M \left(M y_0\right)^{2^m} \to 0$, so $y_m \to 0$ as desired.

Comment: The only problem I see is that it should be $\|G'(1)-G'(t)\|\le \nu(1-t)\|h\|$. This does not change the integral value. // The problem with the Newton step leaving $N$ is indeed the same as in the previous question. // See the Newton-Kantorovich theorem where the same condition is critical.